# xml to csv with xslt

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, omeka

I am trying to transform Omeka XML output to a CSV, and am having an issue getting the XSLT right. Here is a snippet of what the original XML output looks like:

```html
<item itemId="2203" public="1" featured="1">
    <fileContainer>
      <file fileId="3887">
        <src>http://bodies.haa.pitt.edu/files/original/bfbf8515f3b05eca4c506111da66b325.jpg</src>
        <authentication>64676f4fee1b283036fff06961129793</authentication>
      </file>
      <file fileId="3888">
        <src>http://bodies.haa.pitt.edu/files/original/c2690cfd10eeffa32697917df48c9e08.jpg</src>
        <authentication>f21fc08344f0b5e34006e6af2f699bd8</authentication>
      </file>
    </fileContainer>
    <collection collectionId="2">
      <elementSetContainer>
        <elementSet elementSetId="1">
          <name>Dublin Core</name>
          <description>The Dublin Core metadata element set is common to all Omeka records, including items, files, and collections. For more information see, http://dublincore.org/documents/dces/.</description>
          <elementContainer>
            <element elementId="50">
              <name>Title</name>
              <description>A name given to the resource</description>
              <elementTextContainer>
                <elementText elementTextId="62079">
                  <text>Ohio Penitentiary, State Archives Series 1002AV, "Bertillon cards with photographs [graphic], 1888-1919"</text>
                </elementText>
              </elementTextContainer>
            </element>
            <element elementId="41">
              <name>Description</name>
              <description>An account of the resource</description>
              <elementTextContainer>
                <elementText elementTextId="62080">
                  <text>Earliest series of OP cards. </text>
                </elementText>
              </elementTextContainer>
            </element>
            <element elementId="39">
              <name>Creator</name>
              <description>An entity primarily responsible for making the resource</description>
              <elementTextContainer>
                <elementText elementTextId="62081">
                  <text>Ohio Penitentiary </text>
                </elementText>
              </elementTextContainer>
            </element>
            <element elementId="48">
              <name>Source</name>
              <description>A related resource from which the described resource is derived</description>
              <elementTextContainer>
                <elementText elementTextId="62082">
                  <text>1888-1919</text>
                </elementText>
              </elementTextContainer>
            </element>
            <element elementId="43">
              <name>Identifier</name>
              <description>An unambiguous reference to the resource within a given context</description>
              <elementTextContainer>
                <elementText elementTextId="62083">
                  <text>OP1002AV</text>
                </elementText>
              </elementTextContainer>
            </element>
          </elementContainer>
        </elementSet>
      </elementSetContainer>
    </collection>
    <itemType itemTypeId="24">
      <name>Type 1 OP Bertillon Card Form: 1880s Card</name>
      <description>If you do not have any data to enter into an element field please enter n/a</description>
      <elementContainer>
        <element elementId="101">
          <name>Measured at</name>
          <description>This is a date field. If it says anything other than "Ohio Penitentiary" or an abbreviation of that name, mark this record "irregular" below. Please enter the date in the following format: 1902-03-31 for March 31, 1902. If no month or day is provided, please just enter the year (e.g. 1888).</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53093">
              <text>Ohio Penitentiary</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="104">
          <name>Measured by</name>
          <description>Name of Bertillon Officer. Often W.B. Cherington.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53094">
              <text>illegible</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="60">
          <name>Height</name>
          <description>Please enter entire height, in the following format 171.1 for 1m 71.1cm</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53095">
              <text>169.5</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="77">
          <name>Height 2</name>
          <description>Please enter entire height written in red, in the following format 171.1 for 1m 71.1cm</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53096">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="61">
          <name>Stoop</name>
          <description>Usually "English Height." Please enter height, in the following format: 5-8 for 5 ft 8 inches. Mark this record "irregular" below if this field contains anything else but the prisoner's height in feet and inches.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53097">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="78">
          <name>Stoop 2</name>
          <description>Usually "English Height," written in red. Please enter height, in the following format: 5-8 for 5 ft 8 inches. Mark this record "irregular" below if this field contains anything else but the prisoner's height in feet and inches.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53098">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="62">
          <name>Outs. A.</name>
          <description>"Outside Arm," a.k.a., "Reach." Please enter height, in the following format: 176.0 for 1m 76.0cm.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53099">
              <text>182</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="79">
          <name>Outs. A. 2</name>
          <description>"Outside Arm," a.k.a., "Reach." Please enter height, in the following format: 176.0 for 1m 76.0cm. Fill in if a second set of data appears in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53100">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="63">
          <name>Trunk</name>
          <description>"Height of a man seated"</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53101">
              <text>86.1</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="80">
          <name>Trunk 2</name>
          <description>"Height of a man seated." Fill in if a second set of measurements is provided in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53102">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="102">
          <name>Head, lgth</name>
          <description>"Head length"</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53103">
              <text>19.1</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="103">
          <name>Head, lgth 2</name>
          <description>"Head length." Fill in if a second set of measurements is provided in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53104">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="65">
          <name>" wdth</name>
          <description>"Head width"</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53105">
              <text>14.6</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="83">
          <name>" wdth 2</name>
          <description>"Head width." Fill in if a second set of measurements is provided in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53106">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="66">
          <name>R. Ear lgth</name>
          <description>"Right ear length"</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53107">
              <text>6.4</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="82">
          <name>R. Ear lgth 2</name>
          <description>"Right ear length." Fill in if a second set of measurements is provided in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53108">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="67">
          <name>R. Ear wdth</name>
          <description>Usually "Right cheek width," which is denoted by the Bertillon Officer writing in "chk" over the abbreviation "wdth." Mark this record "irregular" below if this field contains anything else but an apparent measurement of the right cheek width.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53109">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="84">
          <name>R. Ear wdth 2</name>
          <description>Usually "Right check width," which is denoted by the Bertillon Officer writing in "chk" over the abbreviation "wdth." Mark this record "irregular below if this field contains anything else but an apparent measurement of the right check width. Fill in if a second set of measurements is provided in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53110">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="68">
          <name>L. Foot</name>
          <description>"Left foot length"</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53111">
              <text>27.8</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="85">
          <name>L. Foot 2</name>
          <description>"Left foot length." Fill in if a second set of measurements is provided in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53112">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="69">
          <name>L. Mid F</name>
          <description>"Left middle finger"</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53113">
              <text>12.4</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="86">
          <name>L. Mid F 2</name>
          <description>"Left middle finger." Fill in if a second set of measurements is provided in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53114">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="70">
          <name>L. Lit. F</name>
          <description>"Left little finger"</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53115">
              <text>9.9</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="87">
          <name>L. Lit. F 2</name>
          <description>"Left little finger." Fill in if a second set of measurements is provided in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53116">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="71">
          <name>L Fore A</name>
          <description>"Left forearm"</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53117">
              <text>48.5</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="88">
          <name>L Fore A 2</name>
          <description>"Left forearm." Fill in if a second set of measurements is provided in red.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53118">
              <text>n/a</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="59">
          <name>Prisoner Number</name>
          <description>Found on the prisoner in the photograph.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53119">
              <text>19148</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="74">
          <name>Anomaly Marker</name>
          <description>Options: irregular, damaged</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53120">
              <text>irregular</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
        <element elementId="76">
          <name>Cataloguer's Notes</name>
          <description>Feel free to wax poetic about anything you notice, here.</description>
          <elementTextContainer>
            <elementText elementTextId="53121">
              <text>the name of the measurer is illegible and the right edge of the card is ripped</text>
            </elementText>
          </elementTextContainer>
        </element>
      </elementContainer>
    </itemType>
    <elementSetContainer>
      <elementSet elementSetId="1">
        <name>Dublin Core</name>
        <description>The Dublin Core metadata element set is common to all Omeka records, including items, files, and collections. For more information see, http://dublincore.org/documents/dces/.</description>
        <elementContainer>
          <element elementId="50">
            <name>Title</name>
            <description>A name given to the resource</description>
            <elementTextContainer>
              <elementText elementTextId="52762">
                <text>Prisoner 19148</text>
              </elementText>
            </elementTextContainer>
          </element>
          <element elementId="39">
            <name>Creator</name>
            <description>An entity primarily responsible for making the resource</description>
            <elementTextContainer>
              <elementText elementTextId="52763">
                <text>Ohio Penitentiary</text>
              </elementText>
            </elementTextContainer>
          </element>
          <element elementId="48">
            <name>Source</name>
            <description>A related resource from which the described resource is derived</description>
            <elementTextContainer>
              <elementText elementTextId="52764">
                <text>Ohio History Connection, Columbus, OH</text>
              </elementText>
            </elementTextContainer>
          </element>
          <element elementId="38">
            <name>Coverage</name>
            <description>The spatial or temporal topic of the resource, the spatial applicability of the resource, or the jurisdiction under which the resource is relevant</description>
            <elementTextContainer>
              <elementText elementTextId="52765">
                <text>Series 1002AV, Box 4040, Folder 1888: 19146-19192 </text>
              </elementText>
            </elementTextContainer>
          </element>
          <element elementId="43">
            <name>Identifier</name>
            <description>An unambiguous reference to the resource within a given context</description>
            <elementTextContainer>
              <elementText elementTextId="52766">
                <text>1002AV_19148</text>
              </elementText>
            </elementTextContainer>
          </element>
        </elementContainer>
      </elementSet>
    </elementSetContainer>
    <tagContainer>
      <tag tagId="1">
        <name>pass1a</name>
      </tag>
    </tagContainer>
  </item>
```

I'd like the output to be:

fileID, Title, Description, Creator, Source
"[filename]","Ohio Penitentiary  State Archives Series 1002AV  Bertillon cards with photographs [graphic]  1888-1919","Earliest series of OP cards.","Ohio Penitentiary","1888-1919"

I am currently using the following XSLT

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
        
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
        
        <xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>",    </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="position()  = last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>"<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
        
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And getting the following output:

"[filename]",    "Dublin CoreThe Dublin Core metadata element set is common to all Omeka records, including items, files, and collections. For more information see, [DC website].TitleA name given to the resourceOhio Penitentiary, State Archives Series 1002AV, "Bertillon cards with photographs [graphic], 1888-1919"DescriptionAn account of the resourceEarliest series of OP cards. CreatorAn entity primarily responsible for making the resourceOhio Penitentiary SourceA related resource from which the described resource is derived1888-1919IdentifierAn unambiguous reference to the resource within a given contextOP1002AV",    "Type 1 OP Bertillon Card Form: 1880s Card

Basically, I am trying to figure out how to modify the XSLT so that I get only what is in the text attribute, and not what is in the description or name attributes. The name will be the column headings.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: hint: `*` matches all elements

Comment: @Pawel ah! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Since your xml file contains only one item, for-each has to be worked out with your real data of xml document. For that single record, you can try the following transformation:

```
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1" />

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="fileContainer/file/@fileId" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="collection/elementSetContainer/elementSet/elementContainer/element[name='Title']/elementTextContainer/elementText/text" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="collection/elementSetContainer/elementSet/elementContainer/element[name='Description']/elementTextContainer/elementText/text" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="collection/elementSetContainer/elementSet/elementContainer/element[name='Creator']/elementTextContainer/elementText/text" />
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="collection/elementSetContainer/elementSet/elementContainer/element[name='Source']/elementTextContainer/elementText/text" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I should have mentioned in my original post, there are actually about 3,000 items. I only included a snippet of one item as the xml is very bulky. I'm editing the original post to reflect what a full item record looks like.